# Pandas Read HDF - Dealing with the Hierarchy

Tags: pandas, hdf5

I have an hdf5 file 'example.h5'. The file has a parent group named: 'master'. 'master' has multiple child groups that are data tables such as data_1, data_2, data_3...etc

I am trying to use pandas 'read_hdf' to read the data_1 table, but can not seem to get past the issue that the master group stands between reading in the file and calling the specific table I want to read. The purpose of this is that I want to read in specific values using the 'where' parameter of read_hdf:

if I try to read in the whole datastore, I will get the following:

```
from pandas import read_hdf
hdf = read_hdf('example.h5')


ValueError: No dataset in HDF5 file
```

Then if I try to get to branch down to the 'master' group:

```
from pandas import read_hdf
hdf = read_hdf('example.h5','master')

TypeError: cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed
```

Ideally I could just do something like this:

```
from pandas import read_hdf
hdf = read_hdf('example.h5','master/data_1')
```

The only problem is I do not know how to implement. So the question is how to access an hdf group that is lower in the hierarchy so that I can use the 'where' parameter to access specific data fast?

ideal solution would look like this:

```
hdf = read_hdf('example.h5','master/data_1',where=['A>10'], columns=['A','B']))
```

Comment: Have you tried `key='/master/data_1'`?

Comment: Yes, I get 'TypeError: cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed'

Comment: What if you do `store = pd.HDFStore('example.h5'); store.groups(); store.close()`, does it output any error?